# Making a drop down nav span the width of the browser even if parent nav has a fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop-down nav that I want to span the width of the browser (similar to what they have here: [iwc](http://www.iwc.com/)), the problem I'm facing is that the parent nav has a fixed width of 960px so the drop down nav is restricted to that width.

Any help? Thanks.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.nav').attr('class', 'shownav');//this removes the css class that is targetted by the rules so .js will now take over
    $('.menu li.shownav').click(function() {
        //will auto slide down content below it for it to fit
        $('ul', this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">    
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>        
                <li class="nav"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul class="products-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>        
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>     
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>     
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>     
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="banner">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.banner {
    background: #007715;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 132px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.menu>li>a {
    color: #007715;
    font-size: 0.813em; /* 13px */
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu>li.nav>ul,.menu>li.shownav>ul { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu>li.nav:hover>ul {
    display: block;
}

.products-nav {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d3d0;
    padding: 40px 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    left: 0;
}

.products-nav>li {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47RHp/)

Comment: As you have `position: relative;` on `.menu>li`, any elements nested inside that which has `position: absolute;` will be relative to `.menu>li` Remove the relative positioning and your `.products-nav` will be page-wide - don't forget to add `left: 0;` to it. OR even better, user: `left: 0; right: 0; width: auto;` and the browser will  make it page-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/cQ6t6/)**</kbd>

```
<li class="nav"><a href="#">Services &#9660;</a>
  <ul class="shownav">
    <li><a href="/">Submenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>        
<li class="nav"><a href="#">Projects &#9660;</a>
  <ul class="shownav">
    <li><a href="/">Submenu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>


.menu li.nav ul,
.menu li.shownav ul { 
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
/*
.menu>li.nav:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
*/
.shownav {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d3d0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 960px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.shownav li {
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.shownav li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}


$(function() {

  $('.nav').click(function() {
    $('.shownav').slideUp(600);
    $(this).find('.shownav')
      .css({
         width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px',
         left: - $(this).offset().left + 'px'
      })
      .stop()
      .slideDown(600);
  });

  $('.shownav').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(600);
  });

});
```

Comment: This is great, but my dropdown menu would slide down once its clicked not hovered (for some reason the on the jsfiddle it would slide down on hover, but on the broswer it worked fine). It's there a way I could make the dropdown slide down on click? Thanks for the help!